# "Where IN" with multiple columns (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

The query would look like this

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from <subquery> where (col1,col2) in <subquery>
```

SQL Server doesn't seem to like that. Any way of implementing that that anyone knows of that doesn't involve converting to varchars or anything else messy?

This is the actual query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM         
 (
    SELECT NEWID() AS guid, UserID, RoleId, ClubId, 0 AS GroupRole
    FROM dbo.Portal_UserRoles

    UNION

    SELECT NEWID() AS guid, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.UserId, 
           dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.ClubId, 
           dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId AS GroupRole
    FROM dbo.Portal_GroupRoles 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Portal_UserGroups 
        ON dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = dbo.Portal_UserGroups.GroupId
  ) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE (derivedtbl_1.RoleId,derivedtbl_1.ClubId) IN 
      (
         SELECT Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, Portal_ClubGroups.ClubId
         FROM Portal_GroupRoles 
         INNER JOIN Portal_ClubGroups
             ON Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = Portal_ClubGroups.GroupId
      )
```

Comment: It would help people to help you if you formatted this more readably.

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to do that.

Comment: It's weird, this question has gotten almost 3k views and not a single upvote.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to separate in two clauses

```
 where col1 in (...) AND col2 in (...)
```

or you could refactor it a little bit

```
select * FROM (
     SELECT NEWID() AS guid, UserID, RoleId, ClubId, 0 AS GroupRole FROM dbo.Portal_UserRoles 
     UNION 
     SELECT NEWID() AS guid, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.UserId, dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.ClubId, dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId AS GroupRoles FROM dbo.Portal_GroupRoles INNER JOIN dbo.Portal_UserGroups ON dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = dbo.Portal_UserGroups.GroupId) 
     AS derivedtbl_1, Portal_GroupRoles, Portal_ClubGroup
where derivedtbl_1.RoleId = Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId
and derivedtbl_1.ClubId = Portal_ClubGroups.ClubId
and Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = Portal_ClubGroups.GroupId
```

Comment: Seems a little excessive to do the same query twice

Comment: nice work, but I have no idea how that "AS derivedtbl_1, Portal_GroupRoles, Portal_ClubGroup" thing works. Have a link or a name for it?

Comment: This is not a good answer: it fails to handle the requirement that col1 and col2 simultaneously match the same single row, and allows it to match if col1 matches any 1 row and col2 matches any 1 row.

Comment: It is called "I am old and started using MSSQL before it has the JOIN keyword" :) Seriously: it is a different way to do joins, you add the tables in the FROM clause and create the join in the WHERE clause

Comment: as derivedtbl_1 is just an alias for the union.  The other two are the other tables in the join (pre SQL-92 syntax).

Comment: @Eduardo: I'm OK with not using joins; I learned SQL before the join notation existed too. I've temporarily withdrawn my down-vote since the long query doesn't do what the short comment about two IN clauses suggests. That suggestion, though, is plain wrong. Please remove it, leaving just the OK bit.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm sure if I follow you completely. I'm aware that the two  IN clauses are not the same that the join. But in this case, I guess that this is what Selkie is trying to accomplish (of course it depends on the logic of the Selkie's app)

Comment: @Eduardo: OK; let's pretend that it is OK - without input from Selkie, we can't be sure.  (Meta-comment: if I make a typo in a comment and there's no response yet, I copy the typo version with control-C, delete the erroneous comment, and then add a new comment with the correction.)

Answer (score 13):

The standard, classic way to do what you seek is an EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM         
    (
        SELECT NEWID() AS guid, UserID, RoleId, ClubId, 0 AS GroupRole
        FROM dbo.Portal_UserRoles

        UNION

        SELECT NEWID() AS guid, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.UserId, 
               dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.ClubId, 
               dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId AS GroupRole
            FROM dbo.Portal_GroupRoles 
                 INNER JOIN dbo.Portal_UserGroups 
                 ON dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = dbo.Portal_UserGroups.GroupId
    ) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE EXISTS
  (
     SELECT Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, Portal_ClubGroups.ClubId
         FROM (Portal_GroupRoles 
               INNER JOIN Portal_ClubGroups
               ON Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = Portal_ClubGroups.GroupId) AS cgr
         WHERE derivedtbl_1.RoleID = cgr.RoleId
           AND derivedtbl_1.ClubId = cgr.ClubId
  )
```

Be wary of splitting the two-column condition into two separate IN clauses; it does not give you the same answer (in general) as the applying the two-column condition in one EXISTS clause.

Answer (score 5):

Do a join on the derived table instead of using the `in`

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
  (
    SELECT NEWID() AS guid, UserID, RoleId, ClubId, 0 AS GroupRole 
    FROM dbo.Portal_UserRoles 

    UNION 

    SELECT NEWID() AS guid, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.UserId, 
           dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, dbo.Portal_UserGroups.ClubId,
           dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId AS GroupRole 
    FROM dbo.Portal_GroupRoles 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Portal_UserGroups 
        ON dbo.Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = dbo.Portal_UserGroups.GroupId
  ) AS derivedtbl_1 

INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, Portal_ClubGroups.ClubId 
    FROM Portal_GroupRoles 
    INNER JOIN Portal_ClubGroups 
        ON Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = Portal_ClubGroups.GroupId
  ) derivedtbl_2
    ON derivedtbl_1.RoleID = derivedtbl_2.RoleID 
      AND derivedtbl_1.ClubId = derivedtbl_2.ClubId
```

Comment: Unfortunately I require a where clause to exist.

Really I should have posted this but it should look like

Select col1, col2, col3 from (subquery) where (col1,col2) in (subquery) OR col2 IS Null, won't work with a join.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    /*      
    your selected fields, joins here
    */
WHERE -- (derivedtbl_1.RoleId,derivedtbl_1.ClubId) IN 
    EXISTS
    (
        -- actually you can change these two fields to * (asterisk ) or 1, whatever, even your name, what matters only is the testing of existence(see below)
        SELECT Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, Portal_ClubGroups.ClubId 
        FROM Portal_GroupRoles 
        INNER JOIN Portal_ClubGroups
        ON Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = Portal_ClubGroups.GroupId

        -- here is your IN (the testing of existence):
        WHERE Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId = derivedtbl_1.RoleId AND 
        AND derivedtbl_1.ClubId = derivedtbl_1.ClubId
      )

alternatively:

SELECT 
    /*      
    your selected fields, joins here
    */
JOIN 
    (
        SELECT Portal_GroupRoles.RoleId, Portal_ClubGroups.ClubId
        FROM Portal_GroupRoles 
        INNER JOIN Portal_ClubGroups
        ON Portal_GroupRoles.GroupId = Portal_ClubGroups.GroupId
    ) X 
    -- here is your IN:
    ON X.RoleId = derivedtbl_1.RoleId
    AND X.ClubId = derivedtbl_1.ClubId
```

Answer (score 2):

Yours is useful syntax and is supported in standard SQL. It is not yet implemented in SQL Server but you may vote for its inclusion [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors).

Comment: onedaywhen provides the best answer if you are coming from an Oracle background into a sql server environment.  The simple answer is no not yet.  There are times when even if you have a well normalized database, that this is a useful query.  SQL standard?  What SQL standard?  I applaud postgresql for warning you upfront that they are following the standard or not or if they are implementing an extension to the standard.